# Automating document creation in Pages

Tags: mac, pages, automation

So my actual question is broader but I'll focus on a specific example to start:

I created a Pages document with some sample text displayed in each of the available fonts for comparison. To do this I ended up having to copy/paste the text over and over, manually selecting a different font for each instance.

How would I go about automating this? Through the Terminal? And, more broadly, how do I automate repetitive tasks like this in any application? Will it depend on the application I'm using or is there a general solution for most cases?

Thanks for your help

Comment: it's not really a task you can automate - nor is doing it in Pages really a good way to do it. Why not either use Font Book, or get a better Fonts utility, there are quite a lot around. They are made for exactly that task. Font Explorer Pro & Suitcase are the ones I've used before.

Comment: Comparing fonts is a not a great example, because there are so many better ways to do that.  Is there some other reason you would want to automate creation of Pages (or TextEdit or Word) docs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As a graphic designer, a huge part of my jobs are logo recreation.  Most of the time, these logos have text that I need to identify what fonts are used.  I actually wound up creating a small AppleScript application for auto scrolling in FontBook. For my purposes, I usually have the original design with their font on one side of the screen and Font Book window right next to it so I can visually compare.

[image]

I actually posted a question on stackoverflow regarding the script I wrote (which nobody replied to LOL) [Applescript for auto scrolling in Font Book](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40625367/6844169)

In that post, I have the full AppleScript code with a complete explanation for all of its functions. It's a great little script for font comparisons and such.  Maybe it could be of some use to you.